# electron-forge: add jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, electron

In my electron - angular app which I created using electron-forge I am trying to import jquery.

I did following steps:

1. installed jquery

   ```
   yarn add jquery --save
   ```
2. installed types

   ```
   yarn add @types/jquery --save
   ```
3. imported into app.module

   ```
   import * as $ from 'jquery';
   ```

When I started app I got

```
index.js:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at index.js:21
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't garantied but try to add into your .angular-cli.json into scripts array

`"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
        ],`

and in your component add after imports other modeles this string 
`declare var $: any;`

in simple angular-cli app it work fine. Sorry for my bad English.